# Prevent viewpager from moving when multi-touch

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager of images that I want to be able to do some multi-touch work with. This includes pinch-zoom and rotation, both of which are two-finger operations. When I do these actions, the ViewPager starts moving back and forth, and once it gets going, it interrupts whatever action I was in the middle of.

As I want to reserve two-finger gestures for certain operations, I only want the ViewPager to react when a single finger is down. How can I control how many fingers are required for a pager swipe? Or must I disable the ViewPager's built-in gesture detection and write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to override the `onTouchEvent` method of the `ViewPager`.

in the `MotionEvent` that you get, you should check the number of fingers. if it's only 1 then call super, if not do whatever you want with it.

**edit**:
you can check the number of the fingers with `event.getPointerCount()`.

Comment: Ideally it would be nice, but unfortunately since the super call must be the first statement, I can't check the point count before that.

Comment: super must be first only in constructors.

Comment: @RotemThis doesn't seem to work at all.  onTouchEvent() is called multiple times throughout the process of page swiping.  When I implement this, to try to prevent multi touch page swiping, forcing only one touch to work, the app crashes when doing multi-touch.

I'm doing this...

    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1)
    {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }